# React and views on registration and confirmation processes

Tags: reactjs

I´m learning React (so understand the why of my question).

- I created an API with AWS and the front-end is React+Redux.
- To access the API data the visitor has to register. For that, it has to create an account.
- Once the visitor created the account, he will receive an email with the confirmation code... Code that he was to provide on my view.

Between the creation view and process and the confirmation view (just and input where user has to enter the code and hit a button), the user can...

- Stay in that page (1)
- Close that tab (2)
- Close the browser (3)

So, and here´s my question: Which is the proper way to NOT render the create user view once the visitor create an account and until he confirms it, in a single page app where the root page renders all the views through conditionals (local state and Redux store).

Initially, I thought in Local state. It worked just for case 1.
Then, I thought… “I can create a localStorage where the key could be user and value the user that we visitor picked. And, until he introduces the code and hit the button, and, consequently remove that item for the localStorage, avoid rendering the create view”.
However, I do want to know you considerations. I´m not a big fan of cookies. Also, 
I didn´t want a Session storage since I want to be persistent.
I will appreciate any kind of suggestion.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local state take one new empty state.
Now set the state value when user introduce the code using 
`this.setState({})` method once you get the code in state you can check the value present in the state or not the time of click event at button. If your state has code then it should go further else you give error message or popup message to user to enter code.